# Geocoder fallback for timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I'm using the `geocoder` gem and trying to create a fallback for when geocoding by IP times out. I've added a `config/initializers/geocoder.rb` file and tried to set the geocoder config with both:

```
Geocoder::Configuration.timeout = 15
```

and

```
Geocoder.configure(
  :timeout          => 15
)
```

However, in either configuration, I still get the error: `Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).` in production; after which, `request.location` is `nil`

I had added this code:

```
@current_location = request.location || Location.default_location
```

in hopes of returning a default location when geocoder times out, but it doesn't seem to be falling back to that and still returns `nil` for `request`.

I've been googling around and so far adding the timeout seems to be the only answer, I'm not sure why mine isn't working though.